# GTA 5 Social club

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, rockstar-games-social-club

I used to play gta 5 online on my ps3 but it ended up breaking and I can't use it anymore I purchased the game for xbox 360 and started playing the game all over again and some of you know how hard that can be specially online.. So I was wondering if I could somehow transfer my old ps3 social club account to my xbox an use it on xbox from now on?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to contact the people at Rockstar Support for this at https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us .  Post a question there. I am sure they wont restore your offline progress, but there is a high possibility they can restore your online progress. YOu will have to provide them your old PSN ID and also you XBox Gamertag. I am sure they will entertain this question as a friend of mine also had this done...